# Get the hours and minutes in TimePicker widget in Nativescript + Angular when click in a button

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

The [Nativescript Timepicker documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/time-picker) says I can use both `loaded` and `timeChange` events in order to inteact with the dates.

However I need  to get the time just when the user press a submit button. Can you give me some guidelines for achieve this? I've using `@ViewChild` for getting the Element by reference although seems not to be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **@ViewChild** to get a reference to your TimePicker and read the current time values. Still, if you prefer, you could also directly use the native `loaded` event to achieve the same thing.

**Example with using a reference from the `loaded` event**

time-picker.component.html

```
<StackLayout class="home-panel">
    <TimePicker #tp (loaded)="onTimePickerLoaded($event)" 
                [hour]="currentHour" [minute]="currentMinute" 
                verticalAlignment="center"></TimePicker>
    <Button text="Submit" (tap)="onSubmit()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

time-picker.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { TimePicker } from "tns-core-modules/ui/time-picker";

@Component({
    selector: "time-picker",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./time-picker.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent {
    currentHour: number = new Date().getHours();
    currentMinute: number = new Date().getMinutes();
    timePicker: TimePicker;

    onTimePickerLoaded(args) {
        this.timePicker = args.object as TimePicker;
    }

    onSubmit(): void {
        console.log("Submit was pressed");

        console.log(this.timePicker.time);
        console.log(this.timePicker.hour);
        console.log(this.timePicker.minute);
    }
}
```

[Playground demo for the above scenario.](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ymLCT3&v=3)

Another possibility is to get the reference via getViewById and with Page DI.

**Example for using Page dependency injection.**

time-picker.component.html

```
<StackLayout class="home-panel">
    <TimePicker #tp id="my-time-picker" (loaded)="onTimePickerLoaded($event)" 
                [hour]="currentHour" [minute]="currentMinute" 
                verticalAlignment="center"></TimePicker>
    <Button text="Submit" (tap)="onSubmit()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

time-picker.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { TimePicker } from "tns-core-modules/ui/time-picker";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./time-picker.component.html",
})
export class HomeComponent {
    currentHour: number = new Date().getHours();
    currentMinute: number = new Date().getMinutes();

    timePicker: TimePicker;

    constructor(private _page: Page) { 
        this._page.on("loaded", () => { 
            this.timePicker = this._page.getViewById("my-time-picker");
        })
    }

    onSubmit(): void {
        console.log("Submit was pressed");

        console.log(this.timePicker.time);
        console.log(this.timePicker.hour);
        console.log(this.timePicker.minute);
    }
}
```

[Playground demo for the above example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ymLCT3&v=4)